# extract text from html without loosing new lines

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string

I use the following code to extract text from html.

```
var html = "first line.&nbsp;<div>second line.&nbsp;</div><div>third line.</div><div><br></div>"
var text = extractContent(html);
console.log("TEXT: " + text);

function extractContent(s) {
   var span = document.createElement('span');
   span.innerHTML = s;
   return span.textContent || span.innerText;
}
```

the result of this code is the text without new lines. but I want the result to replace divs with "\n" like this:

```
first line."\n"second line. "\n" third line."\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `s.replaceAll('&nbsp', '\\n');` to replace the linefeed.
**Note:** The backslash `\` needs to be escaped with another `\`.

```js
var html = "first line.&nbsp;<div>second line.&nbsp;</div><div>third line.</div><div><br></div>"
var text = extractContent(html);
console.log("TEXT: " + text);

function extractContent(s) {
   var span = document.createElement('span');
   s = s.replaceAll('&nbsp', '\\n');
   span.innerHTML = s;
   return span.textContent || span.innerText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.createElement` is not necessary, you can use `regexp` alone to achieve this:

```js
var html = "first line.&nbsp;<div>second line.&nbsp;</div><div>third line.</div><div><br></div>"
var text = extractContent(html);
console.log("TEXT: " + text);

function extractContent(s) {
  
   /*
   *  /(<[^>]+>)+/gim  <---- this regexp to match all html tags and replace them with \n,
   *  also merge empty content html tags into one \n
   * 
   */ 
  return s.replace(/(<[^>]+>)+/gim, "\n");
  
}
```